# mutil-scale mask image mass center problem

Tags: python, image, opencv, binary, mask

now i want to use python3 cv2 lib to find the mass center(moments) of a binary mask,as you can see in this [same mask mutil-scale pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W333W.png),the blue one is the original size mask,and the purple and green ones are the shrinked ones,i guess if i continue to shrink the blue mask, all the smaller version masks will finally converge to a center, the also the mass center of all the smaller version masks will shift, **that is what i want**,so it is possibke to implement it in opencv python?
and how do I call this center?

many thanks!

Comment: How are the masks being shrunk? I don't understand why you can't just use the center of mass of the original largest mask----with normal shrinking operations, the center of mass should be the same the whole time. BTW, you can get the centroid with moments: see for e.g. [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/01/opencv-center-of-contour/).

Comment: i will also try this, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can to get your `center` from the max regions of `the distance map` as follow:

```
left: your origin image 
mid: distmap, blur for the border, purple for the center, green for moments center
right: display in color
```

[image]

```
# 2018.09.23 12:00 (CST)
import numpy as np 
import cv2 

img = cv2.imread("masks.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU|cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
dist = cv2.distanceTransform(threshed, cv2.DIST_C, 3, None, cv2.CV_32F)
## Notice, I just find the first max of the max-regions in the distmap
xid = dist.argmax()
nh, nw = img.shape[:2]
cx = xid%nw
cy = xid//nw
print((cx, cy))
cv2.circle(img, (cx,cy), 5, purple, -1, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Would be dependent on the shape as there could be multiple spots that are all white (e.g. distance transform on a rectangle), though not enough info from OP to get anything better. BTW, check out the Python built-in `divmod()`.